# Mixing smooth scroll and linking to a component using react scoll

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to have both linking to another component and also a smooth scroll using react scroll. I am able to click on login and get to the login page, but from the login page am not able to get to the home page. I click home but nothing happens. I am wondering if React scroll is able to have a mix of both? Any help greatly appreciated and many thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```js
//BootstrapNavbar.js
import { Link } from "react-scroll";

<div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
  <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <Link
      href="/home"
      activeClass="active"
      to="intro"
      spy={true}
      smooth={true}
      duration={1000}
      className="nav-item nav-link"
    >
      Home
    </Link>
    <Link
      href="#"
      activeClass="active"
      to="about"
      spy={true}
      smooth={true}
      duration={1000}
      className="nav-item nav-link"
    >
      About Us
    </Link>
    <Link href="#" activeClass="active" className="nav-item nav-link">
      Portfolios
    </Link>
    <a href="/login" className="nav-item nav-link">
      Login
    </a>
    <Link
      href="#"
      activeClass="active"
      to="contact"
      spy={true}
      smooth={true}
      duration={1000}
      className="nav-item nav-link"
    >
      Contact
    </Link>
  </div>
</div>;
```

```js
//Home.js
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
//App.js
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BootstrapNavbar />
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/login">
        <Login />
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the above issues using react-router-hash-link following this tutorial

https://reactjsexample.com/hash-link-scroll-functionality-for-react-router/